# Ionic 3 where should I store background image file?

Tags: sass, ionic3

Currently my background image is located in src/assets/img/backgroundimage.jpg but everytime I run ionic serve it gives me

> GET http://localhost:8100/build/src/assets/img/backgroundimage.jpg 404
>   (Not Found) theme variable.scss

When I put the image under build/assets it disappears everytime I restart the app please help.

theme variables.scss:

```
ion-content {
  background-image: url('src/assets/img/backgroundimage.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  background: url('src/assets/images/backgroundimage.jpg');
}
```

Comment: you said file is located at src/assets/img/backgroundimg.jpg... but request goes too src/assets/img/backgroundimage.jpg.  Please note the filenames are different.  typo or problemo?

Comment: my bad its a typo when i typed the question(edited).

Comment: Have you tried `assets/img/backgroundimage.jpg`?

Comment: tried it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Did your assets folder originally reside somewhere else, before you did ionic cordova build <plaform> (ios/android etc)? Perhaps you need to re-run the build...

Comment: Have you tried ../assets/img/backgroundimage.jpg